# Geometric interpretation of homological quantities in Artinian local Gorenstein algebras

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

By corollary 3.5. of http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2012-364-09/S0002-9947-2012-05430-4/S0002-9947-2012-05430-4.pdf the classification of local artinian Gorenstein algebras (all algebras here are commutative) over a field $K$ with hilbert function $HF=\{1,n,n,1\}$ is equivalent to the projective classification ofthe hypersurfaces $V(F) \subseteq P_{n-1}(K)$ , where F is a degree three nondegenerate form in n variables.

Questions:

> 1. Is there a geometric/number theoretic interpretation of the sequence of numbers $a_l= dim Ext_A^l(S,S)$ for such algebras A when S denotes the unique simple module S? For example the algebra $A=K[x,y,z]/(yz,xz,xy,y^3-z^3,x^3-z^3)$ corresponds to the elliptic Fermat curve and here we should have that the sequence is equal to $F_{2l}$ (where $F_r$ denotes the Fibanacci sequence). Is there a geometric/number theoretic proof of this without much calculations?
> 2. What is the corresponding sequence in the higher analogues of this elliptic Fermat curve? For example the analogue with 4 variables would probably be $K[x,y,z,w]/(yz,xz,xy,xw,yw,zw,y^3-z^3,x^3-w^3,z^3-w^3)$. Here the sequence should be https://oeis.org/A001353 which leads to the guess that for n variables the sequence might be given by the recurrence $a_n=n a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}$.
>    Is this true, and if yes is there a simple proof avoiding heavy computations?

Comment: You're probably already aware of this but $Ext^1(M,M)=0$ iff all infinitesimal deformations of $M$ are trivial.